# How can I do it in C#?

Tags: c#, iis, config, iis-6, web-administration

[image: How can I do it in c #]

How to set output caching for an application in IIS? Programmatically

Answer (score 2):

You can use OutputCache attribute over action method as below

```
[OutputCache(Duration =20,VaryByParam ="ID")] 
public ActionResult SearchRecord(int ID)
```

> If we want to have same type of OutputCache properties on multiple
>   Action method or multiple controller, then we can use CacheProfile
>   property. CacheProfile has several advantages. For example, we can
>   change OutputCache property at multiple places from one central
>   location and will apply without recompiling our Application. Add
>   Caching section in system.web section, which will contain
>   OutputCacheSettngs. In OutputCacheSettngs, we have added
>   outputCacheProfiles with the name and other properties.
>
> ```
> <caching>  
>       <outputCacheSettings>  
>         <outputCacheProfiles>  
>           <add name="CacheFor100Seconds" duration="100" varyByParam="none" location="Server"/>  
>         </outputCacheProfiles>  
>       </outputCacheSettings>  
> </caching>
> ```
>
> Go to your Action method or controller and add CacheProfile property
>   in OutputCache Action
>
> ```
> [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "CacheFor100Seconds")]  
> public ActionResult MyAction()
> ```

From http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/outputcache-action-filter-in-asp-net-mvc/